# Disposing of textures in an app

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi I have created my first ever app available on Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftball22.topsyturvylite.android&hl=en_GB)
and have had a user encounter a problem where the images disappear and turn into black squares or other weird images.
I experienced this problem in early testing but thought I had removed the problem (I thought I occurred when I removed a texture and then tried to use it again).
I use a TextureManager where I load all images once on starting the app, and refer to them when needed (I thought this better than keep creating new Textures when I reload screens etc). How do I now go about disposing of those textures when the app is closed?
Or would I be better to load the images over and over and dispose of them when each screen is disposed?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could post some of the code you're talking about?